# Android emulator stopped working suddenly today

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've always used the android emulator from the `AVD manager` and it's working fine, but today I was trying to open it and it wasn't working. It only showed this screen and an errors messages.

[image: the screen]

I got these erros from eclipse:
[image: errors]

Comment: Have you turned it off and on again? (The computer... Not the emulator) :D

Comment: @Matt Clark: ya i tried it also but i found one thing that the problem is happening only for the version 4.0.x working good for 4.1.2 and 4.2.2, is that problem with that particular version. even though the problematic(for me) 4.0.x was working fine before.

Comment: Have you upgraded your ADT and SDK to the newer version recently..

Comment: @CRUSADER Thanks crusader, just now i started to upgrade the SDK. How to find out the update is available for ADT?

Comment: @MohamedHussain You have to check manually if update is available or not... There wont be any notification..

Comment: @CRUSADER Updated the SDK, now it is working. Put this in ansewr i will mark as answer.

Comment: @MohamedHussain added in answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the **ADT** and **SDK** generally solves this kind of issue.

Re-start the emulator then-after.

This will certainly help....

Comment: this Works and emulator is up.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the snapshot checkbox of that AVD is not checked.

If yes then just uncheck the checkbox.
Go to `AVD Manager` -> Select the device -> click `Edit` and uncheck the Enabled checkbox.

Also try setting the RAM to 512 Mb.

I hope this works.

**EDIT :**

Please make sure Use Host GPU is checked. Cause checking it enables the hardware OpenGLES emulation.

For further information I suggest you to refer [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the snapshot is unchecked and RAM 512 already, still same result, i got the start up screen.

Comment: now i checked and started the emulator again and i am updating the SDK also as suggested by CRUSADER in comment section above. once working i will update. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem while lunching android emulator... but i fixed it by creating New Android Virtual Device

Comment: Put this answer as a comment. not as a answer.